# gausian blur image processing matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement Image Filters such as Gausian Blur in python.

I encountered a problem when I tried to optimise my code to allow a 5 by 5 kernel.

My aim is to allow any nxn Gausian Kernel to be applied to an image.

The current implementation

```
def gaussianOperator(roi, kernel):
    container = np.copy(roi)
    size = container.shape

    for i in range(size[0] - 2):
        for j in range(size[1] - 2):
            container[i+1][j+1] = np.sum(roi[i:i + 5, j:j + 5].dot(kernel))
            # container[i+1][j+1] = g                                      
            
    return container
```

The error I am currently experiencing after trying to allow n by n kernels is this:

> shapes (5,4) and (5,5) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

The line where I am computing a sum and a dot product used to be like this:

```
 gx = roi[i - 1][j - 1] * kX[0][0] + roi[i][j - 1] * kX[0][2] + roi[i + 1][j - 1] * kX[1][0] + roi[i - 1][j + 1] * kX[1][2] + roi[i][j + 1] * kX[2][0] + roi[i + 1][j + 1] * kX[2][2]
```

This bit of code worked perfectly on a 3 by 3 kernel.

The function to create the kernel is this:

```
def gkern(l=5, sig=1.):
    
    ax = np.linspace(-(l - 1) / 2., (l - 1) / 2., l)
    gauss = np.exp(-0.5 * np.square(ax) / np.square(sig))
    kernel = np.outer(gauss, gauss)
    
    return kernel / np.sum(kernel)
```

How can the code be modified?

Comment: Have you figured out already what the error message is referring to when it says "shapes (5,4)" and "4 (dim 1)"?

Comment: What don't you understand?  Why the `dot` doesn't accept that mix of shapes, or why the arguments have those shapes?  `roi[i:i + 5, j:j + 5]`, `kernel`  It's easier for you to check the shapes than for us.   When slicing `roi` like this, make sure `i` and `j` don't get too big.  The 4 dimension might cause by `j+5` being too large.  Review the `i` and `j` iteration ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating your size 3 kernel case:

```
In [174]: roi = np.arange(10)
     ...: for i in range(roi.shape[0]-2):
     ...:     x = roi[i:i+3]
     ...:     print(x.shape, x)
     ...: 
     ...: 
(3,) [0 1 2]
(3,) [1 2 3]
(3,) [2 3 4]
(3,) [3 4 5]
(3,) [4 5 6]
(3,) [5 6 7]
(3,) [6 7 8]
(3,) [7 8 9]
```

Now size 5:

```
In [175]: roi = np.arange(10)
     ...: for i in range(roi.shape[0]-2):
     ...:     x = roi[i:i+5]
     ...:     print(x.shape, x)
     ...: 
(5,) [0 1 2 3 4]
(5,) [1 2 3 4 5]
(5,) [2 3 4 5 6]
(5,) [3 4 5 6 7]
(5,) [4 5 6 7 8]
(5,) [5 6 7 8 9]
(4,) [6 7 8 9]
(3,) [7 8 9]
```

Oops, `x` is too short in the later iterations

Adjusting the range

```
In [176]: roi = np.arange(10)
     ...: for i in range(roi.shape[0]-4):
     ...:     x = roi[i:i+5]
     ...:     print(x.shape, x)
     ...: 
(5,) [0 1 2 3 4]
(5,) [1 2 3 4 5]
(5,) [2 3 4 5 6]
(5,) [3 4 5 6 7]
(5,) [4 5 6 7 8]
(5,) [5 6 7 8 9]
```

I'll let you generalize this to 2d.